# Shard SVG image into pieces

Tags: image, svg, imagemagick

Say you have a  SVG image such as this:

[image]

Each card is its own svg group, but contains other groups of subelements.

How can you split it up into 52 different images?

Comment: completely depends on the internal structure

Comment: 52 different PNGs, or 52 different SVG files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming each card is in it's own group (`<g>` element) with no dependencies outside the group then:

- copy the root svg element of the original file to 52 files (`<svg ...></svg>`)
- for each card:

  - append the group belonging to the card as a child of the root svg element in one of the new svg files created in step 1.
  - update the viewBox attribute (or width and height) on the root svg element to fit the card (can probably be done automatically by [svg scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour/))